# What are some general registration endpoint best practices regarding the password?

Tags: rest, security, authentication, registration

I'm creating a registration endpoint for a REST API consumed by a simple mobile application and users have to enter a password in the process. (I'm using Node.js, but I'm looking for general guidance here).

Should I send the `password` along with the other params (`firstName`, `lastName`, etc.) or should this be processed via a login endpoint after the fact?

Comment: is your question about login or registration?

Comment: about registration

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the password needs to be passed during both registration (as to store its hash in the DB) and login (as to hash it and compare it to the one in the DB).